# How can I fake a linux character device with D?

Tags: linux-device-driver, d

I would like to fake the LED (character device) of an embedded linux board (BeagleBone Black) in a user space library written in D.

Via the command line the [led driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/leds/leds-class.txt) is [represented to the user space as "device file"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file) (e.g. for led "USER LEDS D2 0"):

```
debian@beaglebone:/sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0$ tree
.
├── brightness
├── device -> ../../../leds
├── invert
├── max_brightness
├── power
│   ├── async
│   ├── autosuspend_delay_ms
│   ├── control
│   ├── runtime_active_kids
│   ├── runtime_active_time
│   ├── runtime_enabled
│   ├── runtime_status
│   ├── runtime_suspended_time
│   └── runtime_usage
├── subsystem -> ../../../../../class/leds
├── trigger
└── uevent
```

Via the command line single entities like e.g. the brightness (turn on and off) can be written to and read from like files:

```
cd /sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0
echo none > trigger
echo 1 > brightness
echo 0 > brightness
```

I consider it reasonable to abstract the whole device as interface and implement a production class and a test class (hand-made fake object) which implements the interface. The client code of the library could then use either the production code or the fake class which could be injected using dependency injection.

Could a mock framework like https://github.com/QAston/DMocks-revived provide functionality to use a fake driver in client code out of the box instead of using the handmade fake led driver described above? (I guess to fake more complicated character devices it would be necessary to "hand-implement" anyway.)

Or are there better approaches to fake a character device (e.g. make the production class require a root path of the driver when creating an instance via "constructor injection")?

Comment: It's just like any other files as far as D is concerned. You can design your wrapper functions however you like.... I don't think your question has much more of an answer than that without getting into plain opinion. Personally, I'd probably not even wrap it at all and just `std.file.write("sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0/trigger", "none");` `std.file.write("sys/class/leds/beaglebone:green:usr0/brightness", "1");` unless there's some compelling reason not to.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe I think he wants to run the code on non-device and have it not fail, so he wants a mock. Still not clear what the actual question is, though.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh I want to use it exactly like you described. However according to test double terminology it is called fake object instead of mock object https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_double in this context.

Comment: @thinwybk not that interested in terminology lawyering. I will point out that it is *still* not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh I will add some example later when I am back home to point out what I mean in detail.

Comment: I had no time to add examples until now. As short hint in advance: I will pass the root directory of the driver (dependency the led class depends on) into the led class via constructor injection for unit testing of the led class. The led class can be mocked in client code using it's interface to implement manual mocks for sure or even using a mock framework.

Comment: Only Linux kernel drivers can expose sysfs nodes. You're better off abstracting away the LED code in your application, then replacing those functions with mocks when testing.

Comment: I do not realy understand what you mean. It would be easier for me if you could relate your suggestion to a fdraft of the implementation here https://github.com/fkromer/dbbhal/blob/master/source/led/led.d . (It is a port of this C++ implementation https://github.com/derekmolloy/exploringBB/blob/master/chp05/makeLEDOOP/makeLEDs.cpp )